# Javascript Regex - word must match with any word from list, in any order, with word boundary

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have the following regex:

```
/^(?=.*?\bapple\b)(?=.*?\b(ipad|itunes)\b).*$/i
```

This matches the word "apple" and one word from the list e.g. "ipad" or "itunes" in any order.

I now need to extend this to have a word boundary e.g. apple can be no more than 10 words from any other in the list.

Can anyone advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This long regex should work for you:

```
^(?=.*?((?:ipad|itunes)(?:\W+\w+){0,10}\W+apple\b|\bapple(?:\W+\w+){0,10}\W+(?:ipad|itunes)\b)).+$
```